# Division by zero when using Ln or Exp function

Tags: delphi, math, delphi-xe5

In my code I sometimes get a division by zero. The debugger consistently points to a line containing an Ln or Exp function.

Using the Ln function. As you can see there is no division at all in this section. vsn stands for very small number and equals 1.0e-100.

```
 if a3 [row] <= 0 then a := vsn else
 if a3 [row] >= 1 then a := 1 - vsn
                  else a := a3 [row];
 costTerm := costTerm -1 * y [row] * Ln (a) -
                  (1 - 1 * y [row]) * Ln (1 - a);
```

Using the Exp function: here a division exists but a fail to see how this can generate a division by zero error.

```
function TBack_Prop.g (value: double): double;
begin
   Result := 1 / (1 + exp (-value));
end; // g //
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. Until you do so there is no question to answer.

Comment: Is there a possibility that this is a misattributed error, and the real problem is a negative input to `Ln`?

Comment: Google for LNXP1.  There are Delphi math libraries that implement ln(x+1) which give more accurate results for small values.

Comment: I guess your bigger problem is that your expression cannot be usefully evaluated at all close to 0 and 1. Your real way forward will involve maths rather than programming.

Comment: @David, I guess you're right about the maths. I'll go into it.

Comment: @Arnold You can ask Google what MCVE is. I could tell you, but then I'd be doing your research for you.

Answer (score 6):

ln(0) will raise a division by zero. In your code you pass 0 to the ln function.

```
var
  I: Double;
  vsn: Double;
begin
  I := 1.0;
  vsn := 1.0e-100;
  I := I - vsn;
  ln(1 - I);
end;
```

Then line `I := I - vsn` does not really do anything. A double has only 15-16 significant digits, so the value of vsn does not modify I. Then you have `ln(1-1)` which is calculating `ln(0)`.

`exp(x)` cannot become less than 0. So I cannot explain the division by 0 in `TBack_Prop.g`. I'd say the exception happens somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't ln domain error an invalid floating point op rather than zero divide?

Comment: `ln(0)` is zero divide, `ln` for a negative number is invalid floating point.

Comment: @Sebastian, any idea how I can change a number by the smallest amount possible? My algorithm might sometimes yield 0 or 1. And are you sure it is purely a decimal problem? Mantissas are subtracted as well and for double they might be as small as about e-308.

Comment: Changing the number by the smallest amount possible won't help you solve your problem.

Comment: You can call `Set8087CW($133f);` at startup of your application. Then you'll get `-INF` as result of ln(0) instead of a division by zero exception (some other fp exceptions will be masked, too). This is often done for multimedia applications. But be careful... this is not a solution for an application where you need to catch floating point exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Not having the rep to make a comment, I must comment by way of an answer.

The smallest workable size for vsn is 1.0e-16 when using real or double precision. This takes care of the first question answered by @Sebastion.

The second question is whether

```
(1 + exp(-value))
```

gives a result of 0, hence division by zero.  Can't happen.
However, a typo

```
(1 - exp(-value)) or (1 - exp(value))
```

could certainly be the culprit, but that's just grabbing at straws.

Comment: I did a copy/paste in this case and I checked again for all certainty. There is no typo (alas :-)